# bing map soap service geocode by only postal code

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I am using Bing Soap services and looking to Geocode using only postal code. When I run below URL in browser it gives coordinates of CA, USA.

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=**00951**&key=BINGMAPKEY

00951 is postal code of Puerto Rico.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you assume the API is going to map your request with a Postcode search?  I suggest you better read the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx . You may need to add more info to your query

Comment: Thanks Héctor Valverde Pareja for sharing link, I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, the search you are referencing is the Bing Maps REST service, not the SOAP services. The SOAP services are a very old legacy service which is nearing end of life. The REST services are the primary service used in Bing Maps.

As for your issue, zip codes are currently not supported for Puerto Rico. The reason you are getting a result for California is that the "951" is a telephone area code in California which is the closest match in the system.